# Opt-out of copy constructor

Tags: c++, g++, default-copy-constructor

This might be a silly question, but...

I've been writing a number of classes that utilize non-copyable members.  These classes are never initialized via the copy constructor in my source.  When I try to compile without supplying my own copy-constructor, g++ throws out many errors about how it can't build a default copy constructor, due to the non-copyable member objects.

**Is there a way to tell the compiler to just not give me a copy constructor?**

**EDIT:**  Yeah... *feels silly*... I had a case where I was invoking the copy-constructor by accident in a boost::bind call.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't actually cause the copy-constructor to be called then it is not an error if the compiler would be unable to generate one. It sounds like you are (possibly indirectly) causing the copy-constructor to be used.

You can suppress the compiler generated one by declaring your own copy-constructor (you don't need to define it if you're not using it). You can place it in the `private` section of your class.

If this changes the error to say that the copy-constructor is inaccessible or you get link errors then you really are causing the copy-construtor to be used and you need to analyze why this is.

Answer (score 9):

The usual way to make things noncopyable is to declare but not define a copy constructor, and make it private so nothing can call it.

The next revision of the language will provide an [explicit way to suppress these generated functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicitly-defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions).

Answer (score 3):

Not in the current version of C++. In C++ 0x, there will be an `=delete;` syntax to tell it that you don't want one of the special member functions the compiler will generate by default if you don't defined one yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Until the new C++ 0x standard is fully supported, the best you can do is to delclare a version of the special member function, but not implement them. Normally they are made private (to help make it clear that they shouldn't be used).

```
Class foo
{
    // ... rest of definition
    private:
        foo (const foo& rhs); // Do Not Implement
        const foo& operator= (const foo& rhs); // Do Not Implement
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No :)

If you want your class to be non-copyable use something like `boost::noncopyable`

```
class MyClass : private boost::noncopyable
{

}
```

or use a parametrizied macro in your class definition that declares a private copy constructor.